# How to replace NumPy array with ordered int?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with three kinds of value:

`a = np.array([150, 50, 200, 50, 150])`

How do I replace the values with ordered integers so that `50`'s are replaced with `0`'s, `150`'s with `1`'s, and `200`'s with `2`'s like so:

`[1, 0, 2, 0, 1]`?

Thank you.

Comment: by ordered, do you mean the rank of the element in a sorted series?

Comment: I would try something like order the list (asc) and find the position of each element in the original lit on the ordered list.

Comment: Try with: `np.floor(a / 100).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use integer division for your requirement.

```
a = a // 100
>>> a
array([1, 0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Yes, it does work for this numbers. Not sure it's what the user wanted.

Comment: Neither am I. OP has only given explicit examples, not any logic, hence hard to infer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.vectorize` if you have to map different numbers to different keys

**Ex:**

```
a = np.array([150, 50, 200, 50, 150, 300])
check_value = {50:0, 150: 1, 200:2}

print(np.vectorize(lambda x: check_value.get(x, x))(a))
```

**Output:**

```
[  1   0   2   0   1 300]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your intention is to replace elements with their corresponding rank when sorted..

```
# sample data
a = np.array([150, 50, 200, 50, 150])

# get the rank of the elment
rank_list = np.unique(np.sort(a))

# get the index of the element in the rank list
output = [np.where(rank_list==x)[0][0] for x in a]
```

`output` will give you `[1, 0, 2, 0, 1]`